Modbus rtu RS485 leading zeros in communication package
We have an inverter connected to an Edge embedded device using RS485 using Modbus RTU. Things were working fine, until some days ago when we received CRC errors from the communication packages received from the inverter.
I get a connection with the inverter and the data is there but there are leading zeros in the communication package, resulting in a CRC error. Something happened resulting the the leading zeros being present.
Does anyone have a clue why these zeros suddenly appeared?
Correct data:
Aug 11 09:35:22  bash[30104]: MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: 01 03 FA 00 14 00 50 00 00 00 01 15 7C 00 00 00 01 13 EC 00 5F 15 18 00 64 00 01 01 F4 00 01 00 01 00 02 1F 40 00 0B 00 01 00 FF 00 01 00 64 02 BC 03 84 04 B0 06 A4 08 34 23 1E 23 00 1F 40 21 34 23 28 23 28 13 24 13 24 13 24 13 24 13 24 13 24 00 14 00 14 00 14 00 14 00 14 00 14 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 01 2A FA FF FF 00 3C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 0A 5A 07 3A 14 1E 12 C0 00 01 13 88 13 88 00 64 03 E8 00 00 00 00 75 30 00 00 AF C8 00 00 01 90 00 00 00 32 00 00 01 86 00 00 00 37 00 03 A2 0E 00 00 14 82 00 00 00 96 00 F0 00 20 13 5A 00 0B 04 CF 00 AA 01 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 0E EB 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 03 03 (255 bytes), roundtrip time: 0.3 ms. Timeout for reading: 500.0 ms.
Wrong data:
Aug 14 08:26:42  bash[3906]: MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 03 FA 00 50 00 00 00 01 15 7C 00 00 00 01 13 EC 00 5F 15 18 00 01 05 D1 00 01 00 01 00 02 1F 40 00 0B 00 01 00 FF 01 00 64 02 BC 03 84 04 B0 06 A4 08 34 23 1E 23 00 00 21 34 23 28 23 28 13 24 13 24 13 24 13 24 13 24 13 24 45 40 40 40 40 40 00 01 00 01 2A FA FF FF 00 3C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 02 40 07 3A 14 1E 12 C0 00 01 13 88 13 88 00 64 03 E8 00 00 00 75 30 00 00 AF C8 00 00 01 90 00 00 00 32 00 00 00 00 00 37 00 03 A2 0E 00 00 14 82 00 00 00 96 00 F0 45 A2 20 10 D0 1D FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 0E EB 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF E5 (244 bytes),
We have a Jetson Nano with GPIO connected to a "sparkfun transceiver breakout - rs-485", which is connected with a RJ45 connector, which is connected to the inverter.
Regards
Tony
The code for the communication:
from minimalmodbus import BYTEORDER_BIG
class ModbusConfigDeye:
    # 9600,8,N,1
    # The name for the uart serial TeleTYpewriter device

    BAUDRATE = 9600
    PARITY = 'N'  # this is serial.PARITY_NONE
    STOPBITS = 1
    BYTESIZE = 8

    READ_TIMEOUT_S = 500/1000.   # in ms, needs to be tested with a long request
    WRITE_TIMEOUT_S = 500/1000.  # in ms, needs to be tested with a long request

    # byte order
    BYTEORDER = BYTEORDER_BIG  # [default]

    # Configurable via the inverter touch screen [1-247]
    MODBUS_INVERTER_ADDR = 1
class RS485ConfigNano:
    PORT = "/dev/ttyTHS1"
    RTS_GPIO_PIN = 18
    TX_PREDELAY = 0.001  # after RTS is`

from config import ModbusConfigDeye as mb
from config import RS485ConfigNano as rs485_config

logger = gen_logger(name='RS485_Nano')

class RS485_Nano(serial.Serial):
    """
    A subclass that replaces the write method with one that toggles RTS
    according to the RS485 settings.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RS485_Nano, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Pin Setup:
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  # BCM pin-numbering scheme from Raspberry Pi
        # set pin as an output pin with optional initial state of HIGH
        self._rts_gpio_pin = 18
        GPIO.setup(self._rts_gpio_pin, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
        self._delay_before_tx = 0.001

    def write(self, b):
        """Write to port, controlling RTS before and after transmitting."""
        if self._rts_gpio_pin is not None:
            # apply level for TX and optional delay
            GPIO.output(self._rts_gpio_pin, GPIO.HIGH)
            logger.debug(f"Set RTS (gpio {self._rts_gpio_pin}) HIGH")
            time.sleep(self._delay_before_tx)
            # write and wait for data to be written
            super(RS485_Nano, self).write(b)
            super(RS485_Nano, self).flush()
            # optional delay and apply level for RX
            GPIO.output(self._rts_gpio_pin, GPIO.LOW)
            logger.debug(f"Set RTS (gpio {self._rts_gpio_pin}) LOW")
        else:
            super(RS485_Nano, self).write(b)

def connect(port=rs485_config.PORT):
    instrument = None
    try:
        # ser = serial.Serial(port=rs485_portname, baudrate=cfg.BAUDRATE, parity=cfg.PARITY, bytesize=cfg.BYTESIZE,
        #                     stopbits=cfg.STOPBITS, rtscts=True, timeout=cfg.READ_TIMEOUT_MS / 1000., write_timeout=cfg.WRITE_TIMEOUT_MS / 1000.)
        attr_str = ', '.join("%s: %s" % item for item in vars(mb).items())
        logger.info(f"Modbus instrument configured as: {attr_str}")
        ser = RS485_Nano(port=port, baudrate=mb.BAUDRATE, parity=mb.PARITY, bytesize=mb.BYTESIZE,
                     stopbits=mb.STOPBITS, rtscts=True, timeout=mb.READ_TIMEOUT_S,
                         write_timeout=mb.WRITE_TIMEOUT_S)

        instrument = Instrument(port=ser, slaveaddress=mb.MODBUS_INVERTER_ADDR, mode=MODE_RTU, debug=True)

        #Good practice
        # instrument.close_port_after_each_call = True
        # instrument.clear_buffers_before_each_transaction = True
        #instrument.precalculate_read_size = True
        #instrument.clear_buffers_before_each_transaction = True
        attr_str = ', '.join("%s: %s" % item for item in vars(mb).items())
        logger.info(f"Modbus instrument configured as: {attr_str}")
        logger.info(f"serial object: {instrument.serial}")
    except Exception:
        logger.error(f"Could not establish connection with rs485 transceiver on {port}")
    finally:
        return instrument


Are you logging the requests as well? Are both these responses to a request for the same registers?

With the info provided we can really only guess (faulty hardware, cabling issue, software bug, inverter that utilises multiple protocols, something else...) which is unlikely to be helpful. Please provide more detail such as Inverter make/Model, MRP, details of the testing you have performed (e.g. connect to the Inverter using a different device/cable and see if you get the same result) etc.

The inverter and the Edge device was working in one location, then we moved it to another room, and it was working for a while then this error was appearing. Therefore I don't think it is the settings.
We use minimalmodbus using python and I saw this note in their documentation:
"Empty bytes added in the beginning or the end on the received message
This is due to interference. Use biasing of modbus lines, by connecting resistors to GND and Vcc from the the two lines. This is sometimes named “failsafe”."
So probably we have to add some resistors.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Ok. I provided some code up there.
